# Mac. Series and nth derivative

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $p$ and $q$ be two positive numbers. Consider the following function $f(x)=x^p \cos(x^q)$. Try to find $f^{n}(0).$ I think we can find by using Mac. series for $f$ which is $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n!} x^{2nq+p}$$
So, $f^{n}(0)=(-1)^n.$ I think I made a mistake. Could you please tell me If what I did was correct or not?

Comment: Why do you think so? The numbers you get from differentiating don't cancel the $(2n)!$.

Comment: Good start, but you must align the coefficients with the exponent.  Start with an example, like $x\cos(x^2)$.  Work that one out carefully.

Comment: @lulu, thank you for your comment. Did you mean that I should use the definition of Mac. series instead of using the general form.

Comment: General form is fine, but look at your sum. The coefficient of $x^k$ is usually $0$.  It's only non zero when $k$ is of the form $2nq+p$ for some $n$.

Comment: What are Mac. series ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, it means a Maclaurin series

Comment: @00GB. I knew but it is so disrespectful ! Why not *Ram* for Ramanujan ?