# Using Mac. Series to find nth derivative

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I posted an question yesterday see [Mac. Series and nth derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4491581/353702), it was a bit hard to do it in this general case. I made my function it is a bit easy to deal with. Consider the following function: $f(x)=x^2 \sin (x^3)$. Mac. series for $f$ is $$ x^5-\frac{x^{11}}{3!}+\frac{x^{17}}{5!}-\frac{x^{23}}{7!}+\frac{x^{29}}{9!}-\dots$$

Mac. series in general is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$.
Now, it is clear that $a_{2n}=0$ and $a_{0}=a_{1}=a_{3}=0$ $$a_{k}=\frac{1}{(\frac{k-2}{3})!}$$
where $k=5,11,17,23,29,\dots$, actually, when $k=3n+2$ and $n=1,2,3,\dots.$

So, I think we are ready to write $ f^{(n)}(0)$
$$f^{(k)}(0)= \begin{cases}   
      \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}k!}{(\frac{k-2}{3})!} & k=3n+2 \ \text{and}\ n=1,2,3,.... \\
    0 & \text{Otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$

Could  you please tell me if you see any thing wrong in my answer?

Comment: I think you have two meanings for $n$. One is the order of derivative, the other is in the formula for $k$. This creates confusion.

Comment: @Andrei, it was a typo . I fixed now

Comment: Not sure it helps much. $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for even $n$. What's $n$?

Comment: @Andrei, sorry again. It was a typo. I fixed.

Comment: This is much better. I can see now that you skipped terms. If you want to calculate $f^{(k)}(0)$, say up to $k=12$, you get $0,1,2$ from the second condition, $4,6,8,10,12$ from the first. In the last case you cover $k=5,8,11$. So you are missing $k=3,7,9$. Also $k=8$ is covered by even case and by the last case ($n=2$), with different results.

Comment: @Andrei, you are right but $k=3,7,9$ will be zero. Perhaps some other terms will be zero as well. How can Infix that ? Can I say like otherwise equal $0$.

Comment: @Andrei, but I kept my formula as defined before and add otherwise it would be zero it should work as well . Right.

Comment: Make sure you try with a couple of terms

Comment: @Andrei, I think it should work now. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning. The series representation of $\sin x$ is:$$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
Plugging in $x^3$ instead of $x$, then multiplying everything with $x^2$ yields:
$$x^2\sin(x^3)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}(x^3)^{2n+1}x^2}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{6n+5}}{(2n+1)!}$$
Then, as you noticed, the derivative is zero, unless the order is equal to one of the powers in the series. So $$f^{(k)}(0)= \begin{cases} \frac{(-1)^n(6n+5)!}{(2n+1)!}&, k=6n+5, n=0,1,2,3,... \\0&, \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$